# Should I create .fla files in Flash Professional and import them into Flash Builder?

Tags: flash

With Flash Builder and Flash Professional at my disposal for creating games, I'm having a hard time figuring out if I should be creating the `.fla` files in Flash Professional and then importing them into Flash Builder, or something else? Does it matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Flash Professional to create graphics and do your animating, building the content as .swfs, and then import those into Flash Builder where you do all the programming. Flash Builder doesn't do anything with .fla files directly.

Comment: Agree. But export your art and sound as swc instead of swf. Then you can use them in flex as classes without so much importing and metatagging.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've picked up a few books on flash game development, but many are working with outdated adobe software, making this step confusing.  This has helped a lot.